# Retrieve data from a table with two foreign keys using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm designing an app where I have three tables Customer,Invoices,Containers. One customer can have many invoices similarly one container can have many invoices, therefore the invoice table have two foreign keys one from customer and one from container. Now I want to retrieve the whole invoices table rather retrieving it with respect to customer or container,and then send the data to the jsp page.
 [Here is the image of database erd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fC2P.png)

The entities look like this.

Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@Column(name="Id")
private Integer Id;

@Column(name="Name")
private String Name;

@Column(name="PhoneNo")
private String PhoneNo;


@Column(name="Email")
private String Email;

@Column(name="Address")
private String Address;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="Customer_Id")
private List<Invoice> invoices;

public Customer(){

}
```

Container.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="container")
    public class Container {

    @Id
    @Column(name="Id")
    private int Id;

    @Column(name="Code")
    private int Code;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private String Name;

    @Column(name="From")
    private String From;

    @Column(name="To")
    private String To;

    @Column(name="Depart")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date Depart;

    @Column(name="Arrival")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date Arrival;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="Container_Id")
    private List<Invoice> invoices;
```

Invoices.java

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="invoice")
 public class Invoice {

@Id
@Column(name="Id")
private int Id;

@Column(name="WeightQty")
private String WeightQty;

@Column(name="Details")
private String Details;

@Column(name="Rate")
private int Rate;

@Column(name="Debit")
private int Debit;

@Column(name="Credit")
private int Credit;

public Invoice(){

}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add many to one binding with customer and container

---

```
     @Entity
         @Table(name="invoice")
         public class Invoice {

        @Id
        @Column(name="Id")
        private int Id;

        @Column(name="WeightQty")
        private String WeightQty;

        @Column(name="Details")
        private String Details;

        @Column(name="Rate")
        private int Rate;

        @Column(name="Debit")
        private int Debit;

        @Column(name="Credit")
        private int Credit;

       @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerid")
private Customer customer;

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "containerid")
private Container container;


        public Invoice(){

        }
```

Comment: Thanks alot. . I was doing one to many uni directional, Still learning hibernate kinda new to it.